# Center of text doesn't work in table after click

Tags: android, onclick, center, android-tablelayout, programmatically-created

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong with my table which is made programmatically. My button is responsible for showing result in my cell. It works fine (correctly centered) the first time I click it. But when I click it again, the result moves to the left of cell (no longer centered). What should I do to fix it ?

```
public int x;
...

    TableRow.LayoutParams rp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    TableRow.LayoutParams ip = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                               TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    TableLayout wt = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tl1);
    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    row1.setLayoutParams(rp);


    final TextView c = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    c.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borders);
    c.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    c.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    c.setLayoutParams(ip);

row1.addView(c);
wt.addView(row1);

a1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.a);
a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
            if(x == 1) {
                c.setText("a");
            } else {
                c.setText("b");
            }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You call [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29), pass an Intent into which you put the resources needed to indentify each image. Use the method [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) to put the data you need tu pass on. Something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("url1",urlMyDomain+ "/image1.png");
intent.putExtra("path1",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath()+"image1.png");
startActivity(intent);
```

In the `onCreate` method of the Activity you start, get the Intent and the extra info in it like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String url1 = intent.getStringExtra("url1");
String path1 = intent.getStringExtra("path1");
```

Comment: This code is in my fragment not activity. Secondly I'm planning make a big table that's why I made it programmaticaly not in xml and I'm worry that sending too much data by intent can make my program slow. But anyway, thx for sharing an idea.

Comment: Did you modify your post ? The answer is not related to it at all.

Comment: It was modified by (moderator?), but sense of question has not changed. I was suprised your answer containing images but I thought, that is only overall example.

Comment: I think this answer was intended to another post. It doesn't make sense to me.